# Evading strings in between on guitar

Tags: chords, electric-guitar

How do I play chords such this one without touch string in the middle (here A)?

[image: G maj 7 chord]

Here is an example of similar situation - screenshot from game Rocksmith.
Blue is D, green is B. 
How do I play without touching G in between?

[image: rocksmith screenshot]

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Remember how, when you first learned, you accidentally touched strings and they didn't sound when they should while you fingered chords? Often because the edge of a finger wasn't exactly placed right, so it damped the next string. Well, you now have to make the same mistake again, but this time, it's on purpose. With part of a finger - sometimes the fleshy bit of the pad when you press a fatter string, sometimes further down a finger - gently touch the string marked with an x. However, sometimes that string is playable with a good note, so don't always take the chord window as gospel, try out. The results are up to you, but I've seen chords portrayed, and sometimes have to question why the 'x' is put there. Your example is one such case, where the 5th string *could* be played on fret 5 with pinky, with it seems no detriment to the sound of the chord of Gmaj7.

Comment: "With part of a finger - sometimes the fleshy bit of the pad when you press a fatter string, sometimes further down a finger - gently touch the string marked with an x." - so I place my finger on a string marked with X, but instead of holding it down (to play it) I hover over it a bit?
   So same finger positions just the pressure is different?